# I want to keep ul li a() hide. When i hover on h2 tag then ul li a() will show

Tags: html, css

Code here :

```css
.contentGruop ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.contentGruop li {
  list-style: outside none none;
}
.contentGruop a{
  color:#fff;
}
.contentGruop{
  display:none;
}
h2{
  display:block;
}
h2:hover + .contentGruop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="TblGreen">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h2><a href="#" class="AGreen">Sweater</a></h2>
      <p>The code business</p>
      <ul class="contentGruop">
        <li><a href="">Intimate-Attire</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Intimate-Attire</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Intimate-Attire</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Its not working. If anyone knows where I can find a code example, or could direct me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Use **`~`** ([General sibling selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)) in place of **`+`** ([Adjacent sibling selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)).

Just like:

```
h2:hover ~ .contentGruop {
  display: block;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.contentGruop {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.contentGruop li {list-style: outside none none;}
.contentGruop a{color:#000;}
.contentGruop{display:none;}

h2{display:block;}

h2:hover ~ .contentGruop {display: block;}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="TblGreen">
        <tr>
         <td>
            <h2><a href="#" class="AGreen">Sweater</a></h2>
            <p>The code business</p>
            <ul class="contentGruop">
                <li><a href="">Intimate-Attire</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Intimate-Attire</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Intimate-Attire</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Saurav Rastogi

Comment: Its working but when hovering its only jumping . To avoid this what i should do ?

Comment: @Farjana You've used `.contentGruop ul {}` but it should be `.contentGruop {}` only. as `<ul>` has the class `.contentGruop`. Updated my answer please have a look. Please accept this answer if this helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Replace and use:

- `~` ([Adjacent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)) in place of `+` ([General sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators))
- `display: none` with `visibility: hidden`
- `display: block` with `visibility: visible`

Using [visibility](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) in place of [display](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) will solve the jumping issue.

`display:none` means that the tag will not appear on the page at all There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.

`visibility:hidden` means that unlike `display:none`, the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page. The tag is rendered, it just isn't seen on the page.

take a look on below code

```css
.contentGruop ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.contentGruop li {
  list-style: outside none none;
}

.contentGruop a {
  color:#000;
}

.contentGruop {
  visibility: hidden;
}

h2 {
  display:block;
}

h2:hover ~ .contentGruop {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="TblGreen">
        <tr>
         <td>
            <h2><a href="#" class="AGreen">Sweater</a></h2>
            <p>The code business</p>
            <ul class="contentGruop">
                <li><a href="">Intimate-Attire</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Intimate-Attire</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Intimate-Attire</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this should help you completely. (y)

Comment: Thanks @pradeep1991singh

Comment: @Farjana welcome, is that what you want? did your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.contentGruop li').hide();
$(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {

            $('.contentGruop li').show();

        },
        mouseleave: function () {

            $('.contentGruop li').hide();
        }
    }, ".AGreen");
});
```

Comment: You can but why would you when all it takes is simply changing a single character in the CSS?